# Can we solve the functions describing the bend of a cable at rest fixed at two positions?

Tags: optimization, physics, classical-mechanics, applications

Assume we have a cable which endpoints is attached to two points at $(x,h)$ and $(x+\Delta_x,h)$.

Further assume it has some mass density distribution, $\rho(m),m \in [0,l]$ and is of some length $l > \Delta_x$.

Let us call its position at $m$ : $(f_x(m),f_y(m))$. 
In other words $f_x$, $f_y$ are such functions so that if only **external (thanks to Andrei)** force is acting downwards $(-g{\bf \hat y})$ (gravity force) everywhere and of course whatever forces needed at the endpoints. Then we seek the equilibrium.

How can we find $f_x,f_y$ given the above arrangement?

---

**Own work:** I think we can maybe try to express it as an energy minimization problem. However I don't know quite how to set it up.

(Other solutions not using energy minimization are also welcome!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you cannot have equilibrium with only one force. You also need the tension in the cable.On any piece of the cable you have three forces: the tension to the left, the tension to the right, and the gravity. 
 What you are describing is the [caternary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catenary) problem.

Comment: Yes sorry, I mean the only force from outside on the cable. Of course there will be forces inside the cable keeping it still. Hmm, I will try to reformulate it.

Comment: If the cable is homogenous ($\rho$ constant) then I think you are right that it will be a caternary but I don't think it will be in a general case.

Comment: If you follow the wikipedia link, you can find the non-homogeneous case as well. Of course, the solution you seek might not have an analytical form (you can calculate it numerically).